# How to get session variables from XML files?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have created a session variable through a wizard method like this:
request.session['cid'] = 1 and i am able to get it from python code by using
request.session.get('cid').
Now i want to get the cid variable from an XML file in order to set a domain
on an window action. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Share your code please so that we understand exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But what i really want is to set a dynamic domain on an action window. As i said i've defined a session variable through python code, i need to get it from the xml file like one does for the user id (uid)

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_planning_planning">
    <field name="name">Planning</field>
    <field name="res_model">planning.planning</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('write_uid','=',uid),('chantier_id','=',1)]</field>

Comment: <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,gantt</field>
</record>
I would like the chantier_id to be dynamic (i should get it from the session)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version you are using this can be achieved in multiple ways.

First of all, you have to save your cid variable as a field in your model:
`cid = fields.Char()`

Then on your view, you can do this:

```
<field name="cid" invisible="1"/>
<field name="domain">[('chantier_id','=',cid)] />
```

This is basically a workaround but does the trick. It is also used by Odoo developers in the codebase and you can find many examples of it.

I can also see on Odoo 10 this technique being used:

```
<field name="ref" invisible="context.get('to_invoice', False)"/>
```

But I am not sure this will work on version 8 so just go with the first option.